# End of file

Tags: c++, файлы

Доброй ночи.

Есть кусок кода, считывающий строки из файла:

```
while((i<num) && (!fin.eof()))
{
//что-то
//после каждой считанной строки из файла выводится выводится строка в консоль.
}
```

И есть файл, с таким содержанием (файл заканчивается в конце 5 строки, больше символов нет):

> ```
> 1 hello helo 0 0
> 2 hello helo 2 4
> 3 hello helo 4 8
> 4 hello helo 6 12
> 5 hello helo 8 16
> ```

При num=5 он считывает правильно все 5 строк, если n=6 и больше, то считывается еще что-то и выводит на 1 строку больше. Похоже, eof находит конец файла не в конце 5 строки, а в начале 6 О_о. В чем может быть ошибка?

В файл записывается строка с `<< endl;` на конце.

Comment: @Cookie, endl, насколько понимаю, является символом перевода строки, оттуда у вас и появляется шестая.

Comment: @Cookie, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

[[@Cookie](/users/30979/cookie)](/users/30979/cookie), к сожалению, в фрагменте кода в своем вопросе Вы опустили собственно чтение из файла.

Скорее всего, после чтения строки (скажем, `getline(fin, str)`) Вы не проверяете, действительно ли прочли `str`, и выводите ее содержимое, а ведь конец файла реально обнаруживается при операции чтения, а вовсе не методом `fin.eof()`, который лишь проверяет ранее установленный признак конца файла.

Правильно читать N строк можно, например, так:

```
 while (i < num && getline(fin, str)) {
   i++;
   cout << str << endl;
   ...
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("test1.txt");
    if( !fin.is_open() )
    {
        std::cout << "\nError opening file.";
        return 1;
    }

    int i = 0;
    int num = 6;
    char Buffer[256];

    do {

        if( fin.getline(Buffer, 80) )
        {
            std::cout << Buffer << "\n";

            ++i;
        }
        else
            break;

    } while( i < num );

    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Приведённый код совершенно не соответствует вопросу. Здесь вы записываете в файл, а вопрос был о чтении из файла.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: Я объяснил развернуто, скорее всего, некоторые люди не видят очевидного. Эта программа показывает, как получить содержимое текстового файла, используя два условия, первое - это проверка при приеме, если строка пуста, цикл завершается, второе условие - индикатор количества линий приема, счетчик полон, программа завершается.